# Database info mising from drush status

Tags: drush

My drush isn't working as expected. I think it's because the database information isn't being read properly. There is no DB info in the status command.

```
httpdocs]# drush st
 Drupal version         :  7.35
 Site URI               :  http://default
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /root/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  7.0.0
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

System info:

Centos 6.6

PHP 5.3.3

MySQL 5.1.73

Comment: What directory are you in when you execute `drush st` ?

Comment: I am in the directory shown in Drupal root

Comment: What is the value for your 'host' setting in your "settings.php" file (within sites/default) ?

Comment: 'host' => '127.0.0.1',

Comment: This issue must be related to version 7. I downgraded to version 6 and the issue went away.

Comment: Try switching to the sites/default folder, or the folder under sites/ for the web site if it's a multi-site setup.